# Format Captions differently for the same table (or figure) [The style of Journal of Finance]

Tags: tables, captions

I have created the following table. Basically the caption includes the label, the title (it is in `\caption{}`) and a caption where I describe the table (which is in `\caption*{}`). The format is similar to the one used in the Journal of Finance.

[image: Figure 1: With small titles it works.]

The problem is that if the title is longer as in the following figure, the table and the title are not centered anymore.

[image]

To create the tables above I used the following code. Using the caption package.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep = newline, labelfont = bf}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{\bf \Large This is the main title.}
  \caption*{This is a second caption describing the table. This is a second caption describing the table. This is a second caption describing the table. This is a second caption describing the table. This is a second caption describing the table. This is a second caption describing the table. This is a second caption describing the table. This is a second caption describing the table. This is a second caption describing the table.} 
  \label{table:rnmSummary} 
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{ l | c || r }
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
    4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
    7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
\captionsetup{justification=centering,singlelinecheck=off}
```

inside a group (to keep the effect local). A complete example:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep = newline, labelfont = bf}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering
  {\captionsetup{justification=centering,singlelinecheck=off} 
  \caption{\bfseries\Large This is the main title and some more words so it spans more than one line.}}
  \caption*{This is a second caption describing the table. This is a second caption describing the table. This is a second caption describing the table. This is a second caption describing the table. This is a second caption describing the table. This is a second caption describing the table. This is a second caption describing the table. This is a second caption describing the table. This is a second caption describing the table.} 
  \label{table:rnmSummary} 
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{ l | c || r }
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
    4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
    7 & 8 & 9 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Of course, if this is going to be used many times, define a command to simplify the code. In the preamble:

```
\newcommand\MyCaption[2][]{%
\begingroup
\captionsetup{justification=centering,singlelinecheck=off,font=bf,textfont=Large} 
  \caption[#1]{This is the main title and some more words so it spans more than one line.}
\endgroup%
}
```

and then, in your document,

```
  \MyCaption{This is the main title and some more words so it spans more than one line.}
```